# Jest, jquery and getting testing files

Tags: jquery, jestjs

Recently have inherited alot of legacy code (jquery code with js with no ES6) with no tests added.

What have decided is to add a test to every newly created method / function, UI changes etc using JEST.

Due to this have a question:

1. Is it possible to test *.js files not being modules? what I mean is a file containig code operaring on DOM injected into HEAD via  
   `<script src="../path_to_script.js></script>` and it's not bundled.
2. and if 'yes' to question 1 what way should I call the testing code? can I do it via require()?

So far have created tests containg code within tests, ie:

```
// elemenytest.spec.js    
jest.dontMock('jquery').dontMock('fs');
  describe('Test', ()=>{
    it('should check jquery element', ()=>{
    let str = "<li class='_class'>I am an element</li>";
    expect( $(str).hasClass('_class')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

however this is not the most efficient way and would like avoid it and work on 'real' files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, have managed to resolve it.

page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header_main--font">header</header>
    <main>
        <h3>main body</h3>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

so to test it parsed file with node, appended file content to document and used jest-jquery-matchers to check if critieria has been met.

```
jest.dontMock('jquery');
const $ = require('jquery');
var fs = require('fs');
const matchers = require('jest-jquery-matchers');

describe('should header', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        var f = fs.readFileSync('./page.html', 'utf-8');
        document.documentElement.innerHTML = f;
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        jest.addMatchers(matchers);
    });

    test('exists in body', () => {
        expect( $('body').find('header') ).toExist();
    });

    test('have text', () => {
        expect( $('header') ).toHaveText('header');
    });

    test('should have class', ()=>{
        expect( $('header') ).toHaveClass('header_main--font');
    });
});
```